# ASP.NET MVC 5 Invalid object name 'dbo.UsersInRoles'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on my ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Here is my Admin code

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Admin()
    {
        return View(UserManager.Users);
    }
```

All I want to do is to be able to delete users from database and its related records in AspNetUserRoles.

I added this into my web.config inside system.web section

> ```
> <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
>   <providers>
>     <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider" 
>          connectionstringname="DefaultConnection" enablepasswordretrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
>     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
>     minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
>     applicationName="/" />
>
>   </providers>
> </membership>
> <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
>   <providers>
>     <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider"
> ```
>
> connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />

When trying to open the /Admin page it throws exception:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.UsersInRoles'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object
> name 'dbo.UsersInRoles'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.UsersInRoles'.]
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1789294    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
> +5340642    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
> RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +377
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
> async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
> ds) +1421
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +137    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41    System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +66
> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
> Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +138
> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
> command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +475
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior) +239
> System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> +10    System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
> entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +97
>
> [EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing
> the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
> entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +181
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext
> context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +1282
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
> +184    System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +448    System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() +270    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
> operation) +251
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
> forMergeOption) +645
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +68    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +68    System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +216
> System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +77    System.Web.Providers.QueryHelper.GetRolesNamesForUser(MembershipContext ctx, String applicationName, String username) +8129    System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) +219    System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +9612755    System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable`1 source,
> Func`2 predicate) +146    System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) +333    System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +379    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
> +143    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__19(AsyncCallback
> asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +1680
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +59    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
> callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback,
> Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +94    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +559    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +82    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
> callback, Object callbackState) +73
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate,
> EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +105    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +588    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +47    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
> callback, Object callbackState) +65
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate,
> EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +139    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +484    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +98  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
> callback, Object callbackState) +73
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate,
> EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag,
> Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +106
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
> httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +446
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
> AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +88
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
> context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +50
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> +301    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
> ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009

Where might I have gone wrong?

Comment: What is your DefaultConnection string? Is it pointing to the right server/db

Comment: hi @ShaiAharoni Yes, I can login, view stuff, logout. the problem happens only when accessing mehtods which have  [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]

Comment: I see... Do you have UsersInRoles table on your DB?

Comment: hi @ShaiAharoni no. I only have AspNetUserRoles. Have no idea where it comes from.

Comment: Well, that's the reason for your error. You probably need to run aspnet_regsql tool in order to generate the missing tables on your DB http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229862(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: hi @ShaiAharoni but I don't need that table anyway. I have AspNetUserRoles which does exactly same job for me. How can I rectify the EF to use the existing AspNetUserRoles table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your problem is due to the new Memebership infrastructure in MVC5.

On This link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

I found the following tip which may help you:

If your app uses the  User.IsInRole() method, add the following to the Web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hi Shai, thank you for reply. But I still need Role Manager, will this disable RoleManager feature in my ASP.NET MVC5 project?

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are very confused about authorization and authentication.  As a quick and brief overview:

MVC 1-2 Used the default FormsAuthentication Framework.  This required using the aspnet_regsql as Shai Aharoni mentioned in the comments.

MVC 3 was introduced with the SimpleMembership Provider Framework.  This extended the default FormsAuthentication Model.  Did not require aspnet_regsql but could be designed to be compatible with it.

MVC 4 was introduced with ASP.Net Identity 1.0.  This completely removed the need for FormsAuthenication.  Is not compatible with aspnet_regsql. This includes adding the following to the webconfig:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  ...
```

MVC 5 was released, and slightly later, ASP.Net Identity 2.0 was released.  I'm pretty sure that Visual Studio 2013 with Update 1 or 2, now automatically uses ASP.Net Identity 2.0 (as they are forwards compatible 100%).

> I added this into my web.config inside system.web section

What you've tried to do is add the now antiquated SimpleMembershipProvider and RoleProvider (Universal Providers) to ASP.Net Identity 1 or 2. This simply won't work out of the box, they are not compatible, they use different tables, different assemblies, etc.

If I load up the default MVC 5 template, which uses Identity 2.0 (with the TKey for User as string, just like 1.0), and a data source the looks like the following:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication3-20140601125344.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication3-20140601125344;Integrated Security=True" />
```

The `AuthrizeAttribute` works, out-of-the-box with no changes made.  They only way I can get the `AuthorizeAttribute` to not work, is if I add the `AllowAnonymousAttribute` at the controller level:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class HomeController
{
  [Authorize]
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

The other possible but not probable problem is that you have Lazy Loading disabled on the ApplicationDbContext/IdentityDbContext **AND** are using an Identity version prior to 2.0-alpha1 [as mentioned in a work item on codeplex](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/1940).

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation. I didn't add the provide and membership sections into my web.config previous and didn't use [AllowAnonymous] either. but still it didn't work. that's why I tried so many wrong ways.

Comment: You should start with the Default MVC 5 template, and see if it works.  If it does, then you'll have to figure out what you changed to prevent it from working.